# C# - How can I declare a variable in MainForm class of type "Generic Class" without specifing generic type

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

I have the following generic class:

```
internal class AutoRegisterThread<T> where T: AutoRegisterAbstract
{
field1....
method1...
}
```

I have 5 classes that implement AutoRegisterAbstract (abstract class).

and in my Main form (internal partial class MainForm : Form), I need to declare a field :

```
AutoRegisterThread<> _currentThread
```

without specifying the generic type, because I may initiate _currentThread as:

```
_currentThread=new AutoRegisterThread<implementedClass1>
```

or

```
_currentThread=new AutoRegisterThread<implementedClass2>
```

_currentThread: will be used across the Form (in many events)

Comment: do you have an example of the exposed methods / properties, will they need to know of the generic type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inherit from a non-generic base class:

```
internal abstract class AutoRegisterThreadBase { }

internal class AutoRegisterThread<T> : AutoRegisterThreadBase 
   where T: AutoRegisterAbstract
{
field1....
method1...
}
```

Your main form field can now be of type `AutoRegisterThreadBase`

Note, if desired, the non-generic parent class can have the same name as the generic class; in your case, `AutoRegisterThread`.

**EDIT**: Extended example, with usage:

```
internal abstract class AutoRegisterThreadBase { /* Leave empty, or put methods that don't depend on typeof(T) */ }
internal abstract class AutoRegisterAbstract { /* Can have whatever code you need */ }

internal class AutoRegisterThread<T> : AutoRegisterThreadBase
    where T : AutoRegisterAbstract
{
    private int someField;
    public void SomeMethod() { }        
}

internal class AutoRegisterWidget : AutoRegisterAbstract { /* An implementation of AutoRegisterAbstract; put any relevant code here */ }

// A type that stores an AutoRegisterThread<T> (as an AutoRegisterThreadBase)
class SomeType
{
    public AutoRegisterThreadBase MyAutoRegisterThread { get; set; }
}

// Your code that uses/calls the above types
class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someType = new SomeType();

        // Any sub-class of AutoRegisterThreadBase, including generic classes, is valid
        someType.MyAutoRegisterThread = new AutoRegisterThread<AutoRegisterWidget>();

        // You can then get a local reference to that type 
        // in the code that's created it - since you know the type here
        var localRefToMyAutoRegisterThread = someType.MyAutoRegisterThread as AutoRegisterThread<AutoRegisterWidget>;
        localRefToMyAutoRegisterThread.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also please note, when using inheritance make sure you are using it when it's appropriate: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how I will pass the type 'T' from "AutoRegisterThread<T>" to AutoRegisterThreadBase , and how I can create an instance of it there.

Comment: To make it clear: I moved all code from AutoRegisterThread<T> to AutoRegisterThreadBase in order to make the call _currentThread.method1. but method1 depends on 'T' as I was creating an instance of it to call its own methods.

Comment: @AlanHawky don't move any code - the base class simply allows you to instantiate any one of the subclasses (that are generic) without knowing which one will be instantiated later.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a generic class in C#, you **have to** provide the type parameter. You could write another class that would not be generic. If there is any logic, that should be shared between generic and non-generic classes, you can move that logic to one more new class.